# Is inheritance the right choice for this 'story and option' based adventure application?

Tags: class, inheritance, game-engine

A friend and myself are creating a Goosebumps-style adventure game, where at each stage the user is presented with a potential set of 4 choices, and the user's choice affects the outcome of the story.

What data structure should I use for this?

**This is my main idea** -- Objects

In trying to keep the game as close to the real life idea of these cards as possible, create one 'card' base class, and have lots of other cards inherit from this - superclass would contain Stringx5( x1story x4choiceStories) intx5 (x1CardIDNumber x4CardIDChoices).

This would then allow me to pump out objects easily with the material we already have, and have a system class controlling all the processing for user choices and displaying information onscreen. And again with the system in place and a base card class, it would allow for different stories in the future and whatnot. Trying to make this as reusable as possible and write as little code as possible (I'm not writing over a thousand `if` Statements.)

One thing that isn't clear to me (and the actual reason I'm posting this question in my inability to find the answer): isn't inheritance meant to be for other classes that are similar but with slight differences, e.g. managers and employees, making my idea completely wrong and a massive waste of memory?

I have looked into the following:

- **Hash tables**: the examples seem to be more phone book oriented, and I don't think it would suit my needs
- **Abstraction to define a story type**: also doesn't seem to suit my needs

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This shouldn't be too bad.  Essentially you need a tree structure.

Your main class could look like (forgive my lack of knowledge of c++)

```
class Node {

   Node option1;
   Node option2;
   Node option3;
   Node option4;   
}
```

So your `Node` instances can point to other instances of `Node`.

It's probably better to have some sort of collection of Node instances, that way you can have as many or as few as you want.  You can add a field to Node that indicates which option it is (1, 2, etc).

The only other thing you need is reference to the initial Node.

Comment: Yup this is pretty much it. Instance's of one class, I don't know why I was thinking about creating lots of classes... *facepalm*

Comment: the using John3136's loop idea, should make this awesome and just adding data being the hard part

Comment: bunnyDrug, you could read the data out of a text file, or a lite weight database.

Answer (score 1):

No real need for inheritance as the cards are exactly the same, just the data on them changes. I'd use inheritance if there were special cards that need to behave differently to all the rest.

You can do what you want with something like this pseudo code:

```
class Card {
    Card getChoice(int i); // returns choices[i]
    string storyText;
    Card[] choices; // Use an stl collection rather than an array for ease of addition.
}
```

Basically you create each card so it links to all the other cards (trick here is making sure you create the cards in the right order - easy solution: create them with no choices and add the different choices via an `addChoice(Card)` method later.

Your `Game` class starts with the first card (basically the head of a tree to all the cards), and does something like:

```
Card runCard(Card card)
{
    Card nextCard = null;
    showStoryText(card);
    // Display a line for each choice in the card and get the user's response.
    // Convert the response to the correct index.
    int selection = promptForAction(card);
    if (selection >= 0 && selection < card.numChoices()) {
        nextCard = card.getChoice(selection);
    }
    return nextCard;
}

void run()
{
    Card card = firstCard;
    while(card != null) {
        card = runCard(card);
    }
}
```